# Every user should be allowed to put/read files in directory, but ONLY the FILE OWNER can delete their files

Tags: ubuntu, files, permissions, directory, users

I'm doing an assignment for school and we have to create a directory where users are allowed to create, read and excecute files. So if user1 creates a file named 'file.txt' user2 should not be allowed to delete this file; however he can read the contents.

Comment: If you run `man chmod`, you’ll find the solution there.

Comment: @StephenKitt I'm stupid for not running that command. You actually helped me, I was doing `chmod +a+rwx` while all i needed was to add a `+t` to the end of that.

Thanks for the quick reply and reminding me to look at documentation.

Comment: No, not stupid, and I’m glad I could help (and that you figured out the answer for your assignment).